# How to compute a value from the src::branch property when definition a build step

Tags: buildbot

I must compute a value for a build step based on the `src::branch` property and based on the available documentation this only seems to be possible by defining [custom renderables](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/configuration/properties.html#custom-renderables).

I created a custom renderable defined as follows:

```py
@implementer(IRenderable)
class DetermineVersion(object):
    def getRenderingFor(self, props):
        if props.hasProperty("src::branch"):
            return "--version=" + props['src::branch'].lower().replace("tag/", "")
        else:
            raise Exception("The property 'branch' (tag/version) must be set")
```

and used it as follows in a build step:

```py
    f.addStep(steps.ShellCommand(
        name="create_tag",
        command=["python", "createTag.py", DetermineVersion()],
    ))
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work as expected and regardless of the fact of the "branch" property is set or not, I always see the exception thrown by my getRenderingFor function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used wrong property name `src::branch` instead of `branch`:

This works as expected:

```py
@implementer(IRenderable)
class DetermineVersion(object):
    def getRenderingFor(self, props):
        if props.hasProperty("branch"):
            return "--version=" + props['branch'].lower().replace("tag/", "")
        else:
            raise Exception("The property 'branch' (tag/version) must be set")
```